# QSqlTableModel: Can't read from model passed as parameter in QML

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qml

I'm using two different `QSqlTableModel` instances to set and retreive data from an SQLite database.
They're being created when constructing an `SqlDatabaseController` class:

**SqlDatabaseController.cpp**

```
SqlDatabaseController::SqlDatabaseController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    // create database driver
    _database = QSqlDatabase::database();

    _contactModel = new SqlContactModel(this, _database);
    _conversationModel = new SqlConversationModel(this, _database);
}
```

I want to retrieve them in QML to pass them to ListView components using Q_PROPERTY:

**SqlDatabaseController.h**

```cpp
class SqlDatabaseController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(SqlContactModel* contactModel READ contactModel WRITE setContactModel NOTIFY contactModelChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(SqlConversationModel* conversationModel READ conversationModel WRITE setConversationModel NOTIFY conversationModelChanged)
// ...
};
```

My data is being inserted in my TableModel:

**SqlContactModel.cpp**

```cpp
void SqlContactModel::addContact(const QString& contactName, const QString& jid, const QByteArray& avatar)
{
    QSqlRecord newRecord = record();
    newRecord.setValue("jid", jid);
    newRecord.setValue("name", contactName);

    // ...
    insertRecord(rowCount(), newRecord);
    submitAll();
}
```

The database controller is being registered in my main function:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
// ...
qmlRegisterType<SqlDatabaseController>("io.taibsu.qxmt", 1, 0, "SqlDatabaseController");
// ...
```

When creating my QML view, I'm creating an instance of my SqlDatabaseController:

**main.qml**

```
SqlDatabaseController {
    id: sqlDatabaseController
    objectName: "sqlDatabaseController"

    onContactModelChanged: {
        console.log("Contact model changed!");
    }
}
```

It's being passed to a different QML component like this:

```
ContactPage {
    id: contacts
    width: parent.width * .25

    sqlDatabaseController: sqlDatabaseController

    // ...
}
```

My ContactsPage component looks as follows:

**ContactPage.qml**

```
Page {
    id: root

    property var sqlDatabaseController

    // ...

    ListView {
        id: contactsView

        anchors.fill: parent

        // ...

        model: sqlDatabaseController.contactModel

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            property string delegateUserName: model.jid // <-- error comes up here

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when trying to start my application and get the model information, I keep getting an error:
`qrc:/ContactPage.qml:47:13: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString`

I previously had my TableModel registered in my main function directly as `SqlContactModel` type, where it worked:

**ContactPage.qml**

```
ListView {
    // ...
    model: SqlContactModel {}

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        property string delegateUserName: model.jid // <-- worked before!
        // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

But now since I had to refactor a lot and switch to a single SqlDatabaseController class it's hard for me to understand why I can't retrieve my model information when using `Q_PROPERTY(contactModel /* ... */)`.

###### How can I get access to data from a model passed via Q_PROPERTY(SqlContactModel* ...) in QML?

When setting a breakpoint in my `data()` function, the debugger won't even halt there.

Expected result:

```
ListView {
    model: sqlDatabaseController.contactModel

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        property string delegateUserName: model.jid // <-- this way
    }
```

returns the data from the `jid` column of my model.

Comment: Don't you need to register both of `Sql***Model` too?

Comment: I would only need to if I would create QML components from them, wouldn't I? @folibis

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess that QML have to know about a specified type anyway. In any case, I would try it, especially since it doesn't work right now.

Comment: I have to rephrase my question to get things clear. Turned out that I can access the model, but not its data.

Comment: @folibis btw when registering the models I am getting a "default constructor missing or ambiguous overloading" error because I have an overloaded constructor in my class which is mandatory so that's not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It was not in the code I provided before, but in my code logic:

I was setting `_database = QSqlDatabase::database();` but then I was calling the constructors of my `QSqlTableModel` instances *before* calling

```
if (!_database.isValid()) {
        _database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
}
```

which was why the TableModel instances set up a `default connection` internally.

I solved it by calling it directly before calling my TableModel constructors:

```cpp
/* 
 * BEFORE
 */

SqlDatabaseController::SqlDatabaseController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    // create database driver
    _database = QSqlDatabase::database();

    _contactModel = new SqlContactModel(this, _database);
    _conversationModel = new SqlConversationModel(this, _database);
}

/*
 * AFTER
 */

SqlDatabaseController::SqlDatabaseController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    // create database driver
    _database = QSqlDatabase::database();

    // this part was in a different function that had been called after
    // constructing the model instances
    if (!_database.isValid()) {
        _database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

        if (!_database.isValid()) {
            qFatal("[SQL] SqlDatabaseController: Cannot add database: %s", qPrintable(_database.lastError().text()));
        }
    }
    // --

    _contactModel = new SqlContactModel(this, _database);
    _conversationModel = new SqlConversationModel(this, _database);
}
```